# Which Event When i close app in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I need to implement event when i close my app in iOS like following pic.

[image]

I want to catch that event when i close app with that minus button.

Which event i need to do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This delegete will be called when your application is going to terminate.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)app
{
}
```

If you are using iOS 4 or greater and with multi-tasking support, `applicationWillTerminate` will not be called.

For receiving the terminate event you need to add `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key on your `info.plist`

Check this [**article**](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/) for a good understanding about application events.

[image: Without mutitasking]

[image: With mutitasking]

Comment: If you use `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` without good reason I will 1-star-vote your app. And there are no good reasons for apps that are developed today. `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` is a major annoyance.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: ya you are right :) But for receiving the terminate event call i iOS 4 or greater there is no way other than this :(

Comment: Even with `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` you can't capture the event that happens when the user "force closes" your app in the multitasking bar. The app will be terminated when the user taps the home button.

Comment: For apps that do not support background execution or are linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user quits the app. For apps that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app simply moves to the background in that case. However, this method may be called in situations where the app is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.

Comment: As mentioned above, the system MAY call applicationWillTerminate: when the system needs to terminate the app when it is RUNNING in background.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to implement the

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)app;
```

method in your app delegate.

([Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW28))

Answer (score 3):

You can handle it in

```
    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

which tells the delegate when the application is about to terminate.

Alternatively, you can listen to to the `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` notification.

See also: [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

`func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene)` if you're using `SceneDelegate`