# Differentiate between system killing app and user killing app in iOS

Tags: ios

I know there have been questions regarding this but I haven't found the answer to this specific question.
In both cases, i.e, user killing the app explicitly or system killing the app (after ~10 minutes of being in background), `applicationWillTerminate` is called. I want to be able to differentiate between the two. Is it possible in iOS7?

Comment: In iOS 4+ the applicationWillTerminate  won't be called if you didn't set the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key. So for this question it is not possible. For reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291910/which-event-when-i-close-app-in-ios/14291944#14291944

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible to do in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that applicationDidEnterBackground will be called ~10 minutes before applicationWillTerminate if it is the system is killing the app. I guess you could use a timer

Comment: It could be that the user killed the app ~10 minutes after the app was in background too. I'm beginning to think there's no proper way to differentiate between the two.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is one. But that should work about most of the time. Why do you need to know this anyways?

Comment: I need to handle the two cases differently. Mainly because of the alerts I need to show and handle other functions of the app accordingly.

Comment: @Shwethascar: it is not possible in iOS 4+, please check my above comment. If you didn't set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key the `applicationWillTerminate` won't be called. If you set that key, then the won't will be closed immediately if user press the home button.

Comment: I don't think you should need to know the difference. If you do, it means that you are probably not following apple guidelines.

Comment: Just for clarification, for others too, if the app crashes (other than user killing it explicitly or system killing it after 10 mins), `applicationWillTerminate` doesn't get called?

Comment: @MidhunMP That is true if I need the app to be killed as soon as it gets suspended (like pressing the home button). But I was referring to the case where after it is in the background the user kills it explicitly versus the system killing the app after 10 mins in the background.

Comment: @Shwethascar: No way to distinguish that case.